# How to annotate line plot with arrow and maximum value?

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, ggpmisc

I am trying to annotate a line plot with an arrow pointing to the highest point in line plot and displaying an arrow and maximum value on the plot. I am using the `mtcars` dataset as my reference. Below is my code.

```
e <- df$mpg
ggplot(df, aes(x=e, y=df$hp)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  annotate("segment", color="blue", x=max(e), xend = max(e), y=max(df$hp), 
            yend=max(df$hp), arrow=arrow())
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Maybe this is of interest: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/233-add-annotations-on-ggplot2-chart.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
labels <- data.frame(mpg = mtcars[which(mtcars$hp == max(mtcars$hp)), "mpg"]+7, hp = mtcars[which(mtcars$hp == max(mtcars$hp)), "hp"],text = paste0("Max value at mpg = ", mtcars[which(mtcars$hp == max(mtcars$hp)), "mpg"], " and hp = ", max(mtcars$hp)))


ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp))+
    geom_line()+
    geom_text(data = labels, aes(label = text))+
    annotate("segment", 
        x=mtcars[which(mtcars$hp == max(mtcars$hp)), "mpg"]+2,
        xend=mtcars[which(mtcars$hp == max(mtcars$hp)), "mpg"]+.2, 
        y= mtcars[which(mtcars$hp == max(mtcars$hp)), "hp"],
        yend= mtcars[which(mtcars$hp == max(mtcars$hp)), "hp"], 
        arrow=arrow(), color = "blue")
```

[image]

Explanation: In order to annotate with the max, we need to find the position of mpg that is the maximum for hp. To do this we use `mtcars[which(mtcars$hp == max(mtcars$hp)), "mpg"]`. The `which()` statement gives us the row possition of that maximum so that we can get the correct value of mpg. Next we annotate with this position adding a little bit of space (i.e., the +2 and +.2) so that it looks nicer. Lastly, we can construct a dataframe with the same positions (but different offset) and use `geom_text()` to add the data label.

Comment: Yes, I would like to display maximum value. If possible can you also provide explanation ?. Thanks !

Comment: Yes, let me update with displaying the maximum value. and then I'll add the explanation with it.

Comment: Great.Thanks in advance !

Comment: Quick question. Why was 7 added to mpg = mtcars[which(mtcars$hp == max(mtcars$hp)), "mpg"]+7  ?

Comment: Purely aesthetic. I added an arbitrary 7 units to offset the text from the arrow. That value will depend on how long your text is and the size of the plot you want to make.  I just changed that number until I found one that looked nice to me. There may be a way to do that more programatically.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an alternative approach using package 'ggpmisc'. The code below uses a *statistic* instead of `annotate()` making it more generally useful. As [`stat_peaks()`](https://docs.r4photobiology.info/ggpmisc/reference/stat_peaks.html) finds the peak and builds the labels on-the-fly this code can be used together with facets or grouped data nearly unchanged. By changing the value passed to `span` it is possible to highlight multiple peaks per group of data.

The main limitation of using `annotate()` is that this function works independently of the ggplot `data`, grouping or facets. With facets the same annotation is replicated in each panel. By design `annotate()` is aimed at adding annotations such as labels that are rather independent of the plotted data.

Highlighting a feature of the data like an observation at the peak, is not a true plot annotation but what is technicaly called a *data label*. The idea of using `geom_text_s()` (the "s" in the name is for segment) is to avoid the need of manual positioning and linking a text label to an observation. To achieve the linking we displace the label with `position_nudge_keep()` which is a variation of `ggplot2::position_nudge()` that keeps a copy of the original location making it possible to draw the label plus a segment or arrow with `ggpp::geom_text_s()` or `ggrepel::geom_text_repel()`.

There is a companion *statistic* `stat_valleys()` that can be used to highlight minima. In 'ggpmisc' (>= 0.4.5) these stats support flipping  *x* and *y* by means of parameter `orientation`.

Note: I added `geom_point()` to highlight the observations.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  stat_peaks(span = NULL,
             geom = "text_s",
             mapping = aes(label = paste(after_stat(y.label), after_stat(x.label))),
             x.label.fmt = "at %.0f mpg",
             y.label.fmt = " Max hp = %.0f",
             segment.colour = "blue",
             arrow = grid::arrow(length = unit(0.1, "inches")),
             position = position_nudge_keep(x = 1, y = 0),
             hjust = 0)
```

[image]

Mapping variable `vs` to the `color` aesthetic creates two groups. For this example we need to tweak the nudging to avoid label overlaps.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp, color = factor(vs))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  stat_peaks(span = NULL,
             geom = "text_s",
             mapping = aes(label = paste(after_stat(y.label), after_stat(x.label))),
             x.label.fmt = "at %.0f mpg ",
             y.label.fmt = " Max hp = %.0f",
             arrow = grid::arrow(length = unit(0.1, "inches")),
             position = position_nudge_keep(x = c(1, -1),  y = 10),
             hjust = c(0, 1))
```

[image]

Or we can use `facet_wrap()` to create panels.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  stat_peaks(span = NULL,
             geom = "text_s",
             mapping = aes(label = paste(after_stat(y.label), after_stat(x.label))),
             x.label.fmt = "at %.0f mpg",
             y.label.fmt = " Max hp = %.0f",
             segment.colour = "blue",
             arrow = grid::arrow(length = unit(0.1, "inches")),
             position = position_nudge_keep(x = 2, y = 10),
             hjust = 0) +
  facet_wrap(~factor(vs))
```

[image]

Bug fixes in 'ggpmisc' (>= 0.4.6) and 'ggpp' (>= 0.4.4) make it possible to highlight multiple peaks and valleys in the same plot. The parameter `span` describes the width of the window (number of consequtive observations) within which a peak or valley is searched for.

I changed the format of mpg values in the labels to include one decimal place.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  stat_valleys(span = 5,
               strict = TRUE,
               geom = "text_s",
               mapping = aes(label = paste(after_stat(y.label), after_stat(x.label))),
               x.label.fmt = "at %.0f mpg ",
               y.label.fmt = "hp = %.0f",
               segment.colour = "blue",
               arrow = grid::arrow(length = unit(0.1, "inches")),
               position = position_nudge_keep(x = -1, y = -20),
               hjust = 1) +
  stat_peaks(span = 5,
             strict = TRUE,
             geom = "text_s",
             mapping = aes(label = paste(after_stat(y.label), after_stat(x.label))),
             x.label.fmt = "at %.0f mpg",
             y.label.fmt = "hp = %.0f\n",
             segment.colour = "red",
             arrow = grid::arrow(length = unit(0.1, "inches")),
             position = position_nudge_keep(x = 1, y = 20),
             hjust = 0) +
 expand_limits(y = 0)
```

[image]

We can flip the plot in the first example in this answer with the help of parameter `orientation`. Because the *y* has become the independent variable we need to edit the text of the label format strings.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +
  geom_line(orientation = "y") +
  geom_point() +
  stat_peaks(span = NULL,
             strict = TRUE,
             geom = "text_s",
             mapping = aes(label = paste(after_stat(x.label), after_stat(y.label))),
             x.label.fmt = "Max hp = %.0f",
             y.label.fmt = "at %.0f mpg ",
             segment.colour = "red",
             arrow = grid::arrow(length = unit(0.1, "inches")),
             position = position_nudge_keep(x = 0, y = 1),
             hjust = 1,
             angle = -90,
             orientation = "y")
```

[image]

Comment: The code example in my original answer had stopped working with a recent update to package 'ggpmisc' (== 0.4.5). I updated the original example code and added new examples and a more detailed explanation.