# Change Arrow linewidth/size in stat_valleys/stat_peaks

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpmisc

I am trying to reproduce the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697870/how-to-annotate-line-plot-with-arrow-and-maximum-value), but alter the arrows to be thicker. I am a bit stumped on how to accomplish this.

I have looked into using the `arrows` function since it has the ability to implement `lwd` but do not know how to get the `mapping` to `x0`, `x1`, `y0`, `y1`. Is there additional arguments that can be passed on to `layer` that can change the linewidth of the arrows?

Comment: Please provide more information: a reprex or at least tell us which geom you trying to use with these stats? And which package are you using ggpmisc or ggspectra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first answer assuming that the question is about `stat_valleys()` and `stat_peaks()` from package 'ggpmisc' and that the geom in use is `geom_segment()` from 'ggplot2', rather than `geom_text_s()` or `geom_label_s()` from package 'ggpp' or `geom_label_repel()` or `geom_text_repel()` from pacakge 'ggrepel'. I will use `stat_peaks()` for the answer as `stat_valleys()` works similarly.

I have used a constant value for the `linewidth` aesthetic, but it is possible to map a variable instead. Arrow tips can be added to segments, segments are most frequently used without arrow tips.

```r
library(ggpmisc)
library(grid)

# lynx is a time.series object
lynx_num.df <-
  try_tibble(lynx,
             col.names = c("year", "lynx"),
             as.numeric = TRUE) # years -> as numeric

ggplot(lynx_num.df, aes(year, lynx)) +
  geom_line() +
  stat_peaks(aes(yend = after_stat(y) + 500), 
             geom = "segment", colour = "red", 
             arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.03, "npc"), ends = "first" ),
             linewidth = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-01 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

It is also possible to use `geom_text_s()`. In the documentation of `stat_peaks()` and `stat_valleys()` there are examples using `geom_text_s()`. In these examples the displacement that creates the arrow is obtained by nudging. These examples can be easily modified by making the label text transparent, which is a kludge, but also works in most cases.

```r
ggplot(lynx_num.df, aes(year, lynx)) +
  geom_line() +
  stat_peaks(colour = "red",
             alpha = 0, alpha.target = "text",
             geom = "text_s",
             position = position_nudge_keep(x = 0, y = 400),
             arrow = arrow(length = grid::unit(1.5, "mm")),
             segment.linewidth = 0.75) +
  expand_limits(y = 7400)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-01 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>